# Error pushing logs to elasticsearch using kafka as input for logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, logstash

Below is my logstash config file logstash.conf. Lotstash reads logs from Kafka topic 'my_topic' and outputs it to elasticsearch index 'es-index'.

```
input {
 kafka {
       bootstrap_servers =>"kafka1.xxx:9092,kafka2.xxx:9092,kafka3.xxx:9092"
       topics => ["my_topic"]
       codec => "json"
       group_id => "logstashgroup"
 }
}
output {
   elasticsearch {
     hosts => ["es1.myhost:9200","es2.myhost:9200","es3.myhost:9200"]
     user => "user123"
     password => "password"
     index => "es-index"
   }
}
filter {
  json {
   source => "message"
   skip_on_invalid_json => true
 }
}
```

It worked fine for a few months but recently it started throwing the following errors:

```
[ERROR][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] An unknown error occurred sending a bulk request to Elasticsearch. We will retry indefinitely {:error_message=>"Could not read from stream: Corrupt GZIP trailer", :error_class=>"Manticore::StreamClosedException"
```

and,

```
[FATAL][logstash.runner          ] An unexpected error occurred! {:error=>org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Received exception when fetching the next record from my_topic-1. If needed, please seek past the record to continue consumption., :backtrace=>["org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$PartitionRecords.fetchRecords(org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/internals/Fetcher.java:1469)", "org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$PartitionRecords.access$1600(org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/internals/Fetcher.java:1328)",
```

then,

```
[ERROR][logstash.javapipeline    ] A plugin had an unrecoverable error. Will restart this plugin.
Plugin: <LogStash::Inputs::Kafka codec=><LogStash::Codecs::JSON id=>"json_9a7a9d96-d7be-4292-a3de-67f797d22ab5"
```

then,

```
Error: Received exception when fetching the next record from my_topic-1. If needed, please seek past the record to continue consumption.
Exception: Java::OrgApacheKafkaCommon::KafkaException
```

and then logstash stops

```
[ERROR][org.logstash.Logstash    ] java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logstash stopped processing because of an error: (SystemExit) exit
```

I'm not sure what's the problem. I couldn't find anything relevant to solve the problem. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure `codec => json` is correct?

Comment: No, But I'm ignoring invalid json with `skip_on_invalid_json => true`.

Comment: And it worked until recently.

Comment: Do you control the producer code? Did you recently enable compression? Else, I'm not sure I understand what `Corrupt GZIP trailer` is trying to tell you. Perhaps you should enable debug logging in logstash or use the stdout output plugin to see what the full messages look like